# Tietze's Extension theorem and Urysohn's Lemma.

Tags: general-topology

*) Use Tietze's Extension theorem to obtain the Urysohn's Lemma.

I do not find the way how to obtain it .Please help me!

Comment: What work have you done, and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a normal space and $A,B$ disjoint closed subsets.

Define $C=A \cup B$, which is closed and $f: C \to \Bbb R$ by

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & x \in A\\ 1 & x \in B\end{cases}$$

and note that $f$ is continuous on $C$ by the pasting lemma (because the closed sets are disjoint and constant maps are continuous). Extend by Tietze and we have
a function as required for the Urysohn lemma.